# execute function after ng-repeat finishes with hidden elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

here is the situation, i have this code

```
<div data-ng-repeat="question in questions" data-ng-if="cQuestion == $index + 1" class="question-animate">
  {{question.question}}-{{$index + 1}}
  <div data-ng-repeat="answer in question.answers">
    {{answer}}&nbsp
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="next" data-ng-click="nextQuestion()"/>
</div>
```

i want to detect when the ng-repeat finishes so i can update cQuestion to show the first question. Since we have  `data-ng-if="cQuestion == $index + 1"` this evaluates to false at first, and the element is not shown, this limits my options  to detect when ng-repeat has finished. i have tried with a directive but since the element is not shown and the directive  isn't fired. the ng-if is there because there is animation hooked to the repeated object.
Now i am doing it with setTimeout, but i think this technique isn't reliable.

Comment: So you want to show the first question and by clicking the button, it should show the next 1, am i right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's move index `cQuestion` out of the view.

Your controller should do the work. 
Create a variable `currentQuestion`, that represents the current displayed question.

```
<div>
  {{currentQuestion.question}}-{{currentQuestionIndex+1}}
  <div data-ng-repeat="answer in currentQuestion.answers">
    {{answer}}&nbsp
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="next" data-ng-click="nextQuestion()"/>
</div>
```

Then make sure, that `nextQuestion` does change the current question:

```
function nextQuestion(){
    $scope.currentQuestion = $scope.questions[$scope.currentQuestionIndex];
    $scope.currentQuestionIndex ++; //init with 0
}
```

Don't forget to init the `$scope.currentQuestion` with the first question at the start of your controller.

Comment: 10x :) this works fine, but now i cant fire the animation, i just changed the first opening <div> to  <div data-ng-show="cQuestion.question.length>0" class="question-animate"> where i have an animation hooked to question-animate but for some reason it doesn't fire, it just appears. can you help me with that?

Comment: maybe check ngAnimate: https://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate